# Environment with specified height

Tags: macros, environments

I want an invisible textbox environment with a specified height. I have some commands I would like to use to print text inside them. This environment is going to be used to diplay the names of authors of an article horizontally. I also want the envrionment to print "et al." at the end of the box if there are too many names to fit in the box. Here is (roughly) what I'm looking for:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,paper=a4,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}


\RequirePackage{DejaVuSans} % Sans-serif
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\by}[2]
{%
    {\centering
    \fontsize{9pt}{11pt} \sffamily \textsf{\MakeUppercase{#1} }\\
    \fontsize{7pt}{10pt} \sffamily \textsf{{#2}} \rmfamily \par}
}
%
\newcommand{\andby}
{%
    {\centering
    \vspace{-0.7em}
    \fontsize{7pt}{10pt} \sffamily \textsf{and}\\
    \rmfamily
    }
}
%
\newcommand{\etal}
{%
    {\centering
    \vspace{-0.7em}
    \fontsize{7pt}{10pt} \sffamily \textsf{et al.}\\
    \rmfamily
    }
}

\newenvironment{authorbox}{ 
    % Some box with height that matches \by text and width \textwidth
}{ 
    % End of box
}


\begin{document}


\begin{authorbox}
\by{Someone}{Tagline}
\andby
\by{Someone}{tagline}
\end{authorbox}


\end{document}
```

I would also like the text in the box centered. If there are only 1 authour (1 `\by` command) it should be displayed in the center. If there are two authors, the word "and" should be in the center.

**NB:** It needs to be able to "adjust" to long names (~ 30 characters including spaces), and also short names. If a long name and a short name is given, "and" should still be in the center.

---

**Edit:** I would like to have some kind of "backwards compatability". Previosly the command has been used like this: `\by{someone}{tagline}` for articles with one author. To avoid comatability issues and having to edit old articles, I want the command `\by{someone}{tagline}` to still work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You can absorb all authors and do some measuring.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,paper=a4,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans} % Sans-serif

\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% for the production version, comment the second definition
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_by_author_print:n
 {
  \makebox[\l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim]{#1}
 }

%%% comment from here
\cs_set_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_by_author_print:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { 0pt }
  \framebox[\l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim]{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
%%% to here

\NewDocumentCommand{\by}{m}
 {
  \vebjorn_by:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__vebjorn_by_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq
\dim_new:N \l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim
\box_new:N \l__vebjorn_by_author_box
\int_new:N \l__vebjorn_by_max_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vebjorn_by:n
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__vebjorn_by_in_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq \l__vebjorn_by_in_seq { \__vebjorn_by_author:nn ##1 }
  \__vebjorn_by_measure:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \l__vebjorn_by_fil:
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq < 3 } { \hfil } { \hfill }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_by_author:nn
 {
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \fontsize{9}{11}\sffamily \text_uppercase:n{#1} \\[1ex]
    \fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily #2
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_by_measure:
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq \__vebjorn_by_measure_author:n
  \int_set:Nn \l__vebjorn_by_max_int { \textwidth / \l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim - 1 }
  % now we can print!
  \begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq
   {
    \__vebjorn_by_author_print:n {##2}
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 < \l__vebjorn_by_max_int }
     {
      \int_compare:nT { ##1 < \seq_count:N \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq }
       {
        {\l__vebjorn_by_fil:\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily and\l__vebjorn_by_fil:}
       }
     }
     {
      \int_compare:nT { \l__vebjorn_by_max_int < \seq_count:N \l__vebjorn_by_out_seq }
       {% we've got more authors than they fit
        \seq_map_break:n { \l__vebjorn_by_fil:\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily et~al. }
       }
     }
   }
  \end{center}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_by_measure_author:n
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__vebjorn_by_author_box
   {
    #1
    {\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily\quad and \quad}
   }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \l__vebjorn_by_widest_dim } { \box_wd:N \l__vebjorn_by_author_box }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline}
}

\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone Else}{tagline}
}

\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone Else}{tagline} \\
  {Someone 2}{Tagline}
}

\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone Else}{tagline} \\
  {Someone 2}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone 3}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone 4}{Tagline}
}

\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone Else}{tagline} \\
  {Someone 2}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone 3}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone 4}{Tagline} \\
  {Someone 5}{Tagline}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have it not centered for 3 and more people, but instead just try to fit as many authors as possible? If you have 1 long name and 3 short names, the long name will make the short names take up too much space because of centering.

Comment: Also, It would be nice to be able to use the old version of ``\by`` for backwards comatability: ``\by{someone}{tagline}``. Then one would not have to edit old articles to be able to use them, and one can have the names displayed verticually if desirable.